# Yii::$app not available in model's fields()

Tags: php, yii

Here is part of code of my model:

```
public function fields()
    {
        //print_r(Yii::$app->controller->action->uniqueId);
   if(Yii::$app->controller->action->uniqueId == 'user/self' or
            Yii::$app->controller->action->uniqueId == 'user/confirm' or
            Yii::$app->controller->action->uniqueId == 'user/create'){

            if( $this->status == self::STATUS_ACTIVE)
            return [ .......
```

The line with Yii::$app return "Trying to get property of none object". And yes, Yii::$app return NULL instead of its object. How this could be happen? Should I attach some settings?

upd:
stack-trace

```
"stack-trace": [
    "#0 /var/www/millennials.kz/public_html/models/User.php(218): yii\\base\\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/var/www/millen...', 218, Array)",
    "#1 /var/www/millennials.kz/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ArrayableTrait.php(143): app\\models\\User->fields()",
    "#2 /var/www/millennials.kz/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ArrayableTrait.php(119): yii\\base\\Model->resolveFields(Array, Array)",
    "#3 /var/www/millennials.kz/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseJson.php(145): yii\\base\\Model->toArray()",
    "#4 /var/www/millennials.kz/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseJson.php(164): yii\\helpers\\BaseJson::processData(Object(app\\models\\User), Array, '57c87a13d611d6....')",
    "#5 /var/www/millennials.kz/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseJson.php(55): yii\\helpers\\BaseJson::processData(Array, Array, '57c87a13d611d6....')",
    "#6 /var/www/millennials.kz/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/JsonResponseFormatter.php(89): yii\\helpers\\BaseJson::encode(Array, 320)",
    "#7 /var/www/millennials.kz/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/JsonResponseFormatter.php(73): yii\\web\\JsonResponseFormatter->formatJson(Object(yii\\web\\Response))",
    "#8 /var/www/millennials.kz/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(947): yii\\web\\JsonResponseFormatter->format(Object(yii\\web\\Response))",
    "#9 /var/www/millennials.kz/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(311): yii\\web\\Response->prepare()",
    "#10 /var/www/millennials.kz/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(381): yii\\web\\Response->send()",
    "#11 /var/www/millennials.kz/public_html/web/index.php(12): yii\\base\\Application->run()",
    "#12 {main}"
  ]
```

Comment: Do you use namespace? e.g. use Yii;

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis Yes I have it, right on the top. And the namespace of model is usual - namespace app\models;

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis also one moment I didn't mentioned: this code have been work on different server, then after 2 months I changed the server and few days ago deployed to the new one (centos 7, digitalocean), in general app seems to be working except this strange behavior of Yii::$app

Comment: Very strange. It must be a path issue. Try adding slashes. e.g: \Yii::$app

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis same thing, wanna see the stack-trace?

Comment: Yes. Add it to the question.

Comment: Do you get same error when you uncommented 
//print_r(Yii::$app->controller->action->uniqueId);

Comment: @AbhishekJain yep, it tells no object. When I try to print out Yii::$app it returns null

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this:

```
  public function fields() {
    $fields = parent::fields();
    $fields["some"] = function () {
        if (Yii::$app->controller->action->uniqueId == 'user/self' or
                Yii::$app->controller->action->uniqueId == 'user/confirm' or
                Yii::$app->controller->action->uniqueId == 'user/create') {

            if ($this->status == self::STATUS_ACTIVE) {
                return "test";
            } else {

                return "zzz";
            }
        } else {

            return "tttt";
        }
    };

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: in function fields.you should use function callback.in detail ,you should see yii framework sourec code.

Comment: please show me you codes detail.Maybe I can solve it.

Comment: it doesn't matter, obviously that the trouble is in "Yii::$app->controller->action->uniqueId" this calling. There are two ways I think: 1) change somehow the path to Yii, because it' been broken after relocation 2) check is Yii class even exist. So dear @yage10548 how can I check work of Yii::$app in general? Maybe go though the files three and check is it there. ps: at the top of model I have "use Yii;"